# The OBJ Model not loading in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm attempting to load an OBJ Model (WoodfordShaleMerged_FUTM.obj) using the React Three Fiber library, but I'm encountering an issue where the model isn't being loaded. I've provided my code in the CodeSandbox link below for reference:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objloader-forked-zd99km?file=/src/App.js)

Interestingly, the model appears to load successfully when using https://3dviewer.net, ruling out any problems with the model itself. Additionally, I tested loading another model (Poimandres.obj) and it worked as expected.

One important note: The WoodfordShaleMerged_FUTM.obj file contains a large number of vertices (v). Could this potentially be causing the loading issue in React Three Fiber?

My App.js component:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";
import { MTLLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader";
import { DDSLoader } from "three-stdlib";
import { Suspense } from "react";

THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.addHandler(/\.dds$/i, new DDSLoader());

const Scene = () => {
  const materials = useLoader(MTLLoader, "AinsaQuarrySUTM.mtl");
  const obj = useLoader(OBJLoader, "AinsaQuarrySUTM.obj", (loader) => {
    materials.preload();
    loader.setMaterials(materials);
  });

  console.log(obj);
  return <primitive object={obj} scale={0.4} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas style={{ background: "green" }}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Scene />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```